# 2 Models of same Properties, MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, object, inheritance, properties, mode

Good Day guys!

I've just started using MVC3, I've 2 models in my application i.e. "Page" and "PageHistory" both has same properties. except that "PageHistory" has one extra property called "PageId" which references the "Page" model.

My question is am doing it in correct way? or should I use inheritance for this. 
If inheritance is a option, How can I handle this, any examples will help me a lot.

My Model looks like as follows:

```
public class Page
    {
        private readonly IndianTime _g = new IndianTime();

        public Page()
        {
            CreatedOn = _g.DateTime;
            Properties = "Published";
            Tags = "Page";
            RelativeUrl = string.Empty;
        }

        public string Path
        {
            get { return (ParentPage != null) ? ParentPage.Heading + " >> " + Heading : Heading; }
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200), Required, DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200), Required, DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Heading { get; set; }

        [MaxLength, Required, DataType(DataType.Html)]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Reference Code"), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Remote("CheckDuplicate", "Page", ErrorMessage = "Url has already taken", AdditionalFields = "initialUrl")]
        public string Url { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Created On"), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        //Parent Page Object (Self Reference: ParentId = > Id)
        [Display(Name = "Parent Page")]
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Root")]
        public virtual Page ParentPage { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Page> ChildPages { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think inheritance will be the right way, the current structure looks ok to me.

See if you choose to make the Page as parent, and Pagehistory as being inherited from Page which actually it is not its just the pagehistory quite simply put.

Your idea of inheritance should always come from real world implementations, for ex. there could be diff. kinds of pages all inheriting from a Super Page type, while Page history is just a property to the page rather a complex property with properties inside it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. What I was thinking that, Should I write the same set of model code? Because both models are same; only thing is "PageHistory" table will be filled only when I do change the values of any record in "Page" table.

Comment: well your thought process is just right to reduce the code, but sometimes a little more of it won't hurt, but i would still see if there is a chance to make Pagehistory a property of Page, but if you have got it like that due to some business rule let it be.  I do understand that Page history is rather a diff type in your system because you might would like to fetch just pagehistories